# Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m how do I search source files using Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

**Chrome Version "32.0.1700.76 m"**. How do I search resources.
Using Devtools, how can I search through all my resources for specific **javaScript** not knowing which file it's in.  This feature used to work and now I can't figure out how to.

Comment: "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."  this is a programming tool and on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On version 32x you may search across all sources by following these steps:

1. Open Devtools
2. Press Cmd + Option + F on OSX, or Ctrl + Shift + F on Windows
3. Enter your search criteria in the search box (see image below)
4. Press the Enter key

[image]

Comment: Pretty much discovered this right after posting my question. Thanks!!